# How to delete string element from 3d array in c

Tags: c, sorting, multidimensional-array

I want to delete complete row in this 3d array specific of my choice by just using name or [x][0] element , but how?

```
char arr[4][6][20] = {
    {"Zack","NY","29-01-1992","Engr","male","gaming"},
    {"Charles","DC","21-04-1994","Doc","male","hockey"},
    {"Alina","Pen","12-05-1991","Law","female","painting"},
    {"etc","LN","19-01-1990","techer","male","bicycle"},
};
// c is the element i want to delete
// i am using this procedure to delete the row
for(c = 1; c < 4 - 1; ++c){
    for(z = 0;z < 6;++z){
        arr[c][z][20] = arr[c+1][z];
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot. C-style arrays have fixed length. If you are using C++, use `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>` instead.

Comment: Are you using C or C++?

Comment: Why not using a struct, and list with you want to manipulate some element ?
In C you cannot delete just set to another value or realloc arr

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> arr = {{"Zack", "NY", etc...}, {"Charles", etc.... }};`, then `arr.erase(arr.begin());` to erase the first entry.  Literally one line of C++ code to do the job.  The issue is that you have not mentioned what language you are actually using.

Comment: Your actual issue is this: `arr[c][z][20] = arr[c+1][z];` The size of your most inner dimension is `[20]`. Hence, the index `[20]` on the left-hand-side is out-of-range. You probably intended to address the whole array. That would have been `arr[c][z] = arr[c+1][z];` but now, you have a new problem: Assignment of arrays is not supported (neither in C nor in C++). For this, there are `strcpy()` and `memcpy()` provided in the standard libraries.

Comment: As you cannot delete a row (as already mentioned), you might consider to clear the row instead i.e. store empty strings in all columns. You already tried to shift all the rows (following after the deleted row) one row down. What you still should add, is a code to clear the last row finally. That could be e.g. `for (z = 0; z < 6; ++z) arr[3][z][0] = '\0';`. Thereby, the first character of each column (of the last row) is overridden with `'\0'`. That makes it an empty C string regardless what other characters follow.

Comment: I'm using c language .... just simply upload the solution code that should work fine with my requirement if possible

Comment: `for(c = d - 1; c < SIZE -1; ++c){for(z = 0;z < 6;++z){strcpy(arr[c][z],arr[c+1][z]);}}` 
@Scheff this code is working well